# Incompatible type. Need support.v4.app.Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-support-library

I am trying to use google source project and stuck with this problem - I want to use AlarmClockFragment with my viewpager but can't because AlarmClockFragment class extends DeskClockFragment (which extends v4.app.Fragment) but not v4.app.fragment directly that why I get incompatible types errors. Could someone help me cast it or restructure my class so it will be compatible?

[image]

[image]

EXTRA**********
[image]

Comment: "...DeskClockFragment (which extends v4.app.Fragment)..." - Are you certain of that? The only `DeskClockFragment` classes I can find on googlesource extend `android.app.Fragment`. "...but not v4.app.fragment directly that why I get imcompatible types errors." - That's not correct.

Comment: You're right! Sorry it's 4am, missed it. So I just reimport v4 version and adjust my code to it, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what your class looks like, exactly, but the ones I pulled up were pretty simple. Yeah, you can probably just change the `import` in `DeskClockFragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, and be good to go.

Comment: You don't need those `FragmentCompat` helpers, since you're using support `Fragment`s. Just call the `setUserVisibleHint()` and `setMenuVisibility()` methods directly.

Comment: Just did that! Thanks so much!!

Comment: No problem. You can probably just delete this, if you want, since the cause was just a mistaken class. Glad you got it figured out. Cheers!